# What happens to active TCP sessions when the active slave fails in a Linux bond (failove or LACP)?

Tags: linux, networking, bonding, lacp

Given an active-backup (mode 3) or 802.3ad (mode 4) type bond, when the active slave fails, is there any seamless failover for those TCP/IP connections that were active prior to and at the time of the failure?

Given server A which has active TCP connections with server B, with server A suffering a NIC failure. Am I correct in assuming that at the time of the NIC failure on server A, server B will stop receiving packets from server A for the established TCP connections? Server B will start sending retransmission requests, while the bonding driver on server A waits for the downdelay to expire, then proceeds to make the backup NIC as the new active slave. If this happens before the existing connections time out, communication will seamlessly resume, without those connections being torn down?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The active/passive thing should work on a lower level than TCP so there will be no visible impact on TCP connections.